# Can not start MongoDB within a specific folder instead of C:\\mongodb\bin directory

Tags: windows, mongodb

I cannot start MongoDB within another specific folder rather than c:\mongodb\bin directory.Please check my following command.

```
1-opened my cmd.
2-`run mongod --dbpath C:\Documents and Settings\Subhrajyoti\Desktop\htdocs\swargadwara\db`
```

but the above steps gave me the following error message.

```
'mongod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

For the above error message i set `c:\\mongodb` in environment variable path.But again i got the same error.In second time i followed the below steps.

```
1-> moved to c:\\mongodb\bin directory in cmd.
2-> run command mongod --dbpath pathname(i.e.C:\Documents and Settings\Subhrajyoti\Desktop\htdocs\swargadwara\db`).
```

again it gave me the following message.

```
2015-05-06T17:21:06.828+0530 I CONTROL
2015-05-06T17:21:06.828+0530 W CONTROL  32-bit servers don't have journaling ena
bled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
2015-05-06T17:21:06.828+0530 I CONTROL
Invalid command: and
Options:

General options:
  -h [ --help ]                  show this usage information
  --version                      show version information
  -f [ --config ] arg            configuration file specifying additional
                                 options
  -v [ --verbose ] [=arg(=v)]    be more verbose (include multiple times for
                                 more verbosity e.g. -vvvvv)
  --quiet                        quieter output
  --port arg                     specify port number - 27017 by default
  --bind_ip arg                  comma separated list of ip addresses to listen
                                 on - all local ips by default
  --ipv6                         enable IPv6 support (disabled by default)
  --maxConns arg                 max number of simultaneous connections -
                                 1000000 by default
  --logpath arg                  log file to send write to instead of stdout -
                                 has to be a file, not directory
  --logappend                    append to logpath instead of over-writing
  --logRotate arg                set the log rotation behavior (rename|reopen)
  --timeStampFormat arg          Desired format for timestamps in log messages.
                                 One of ctime, iso8601-utc or iso8601-local
  --pidfilepath arg              full path to pidfile (if not set, no pidfile
                                 is created)
  --keyFile arg                  private key for cluster authentication
  --setParameter arg             Set a configurable parameter
  --httpinterface                enable http interface
  --clusterAuthMode arg          Authentication mode used for cluster
                                 authentication. Alternatives are
                                 (keyFile|sendKeyFile|sendX509|x509)
  --auth                         run with security
  --noauth                       run without security
  --jsonp                        allow JSONP access via http (has security
                                 implications)
  --rest                         turn on simple rest api
  --slowms arg (=100)            value of slow for profile and console log
  --profile arg                  0=off 1=slow, 2=all
  --cpu                          periodically show cpu and iowait utilization
  --sysinfo                      print some diagnostic system information
  --noIndexBuildRetry            don't retry any index builds that were
                                 interrupted by shutdown
  --noscripting                  disable scripting engine
  --notablescan                  do not allow table scans

Windows Service Control Manager options:
  --install                      install Windows service
  --remove                       remove Windows service
  --reinstall                    reinstall Windows service (equivalent to
                                 --remove followed by --install)
  --serviceName arg              Windows service name
  --serviceDisplayName arg       Windows service display name
  --serviceDescription arg       Windows service description
  --serviceUser arg              account for service execution
  --servicePassword arg          password used to authenticate serviceUser

Replication options:
  --oplogSize arg                size to use (in MB) for replication op log.
                                 default is 5% of disk space (i.e. large is
                                 good)

Master/slave options (old; use replica sets instead):
  --master                       master mode
  --slave                        slave mode
  --source arg                   when slave: specify master as <server:port>
  --only arg                     when slave: specify a single database to
                                 replicate
  --slavedelay arg               specify delay (in seconds) to be used when
                                 applying master ops to slave
  --autoresync                   automatically resync if slave data is stale

Replica set options:
  --replSet arg                  arg is <setname>[/<optionalseedhostlist>]
  --replIndexPrefetch arg        specify index prefetching behavior (if
                                 secondary) [none|_id_only|all]

Sharding options:
  --configsvr                    declare this is a config db of a cluster;
                                 default port 27019; default dir /data/configdb
  --shardsvr                     declare this is a shard db of a cluster;
                                 default port 27018

Storage options:
  --storageEngine arg (=mmapv1)  what storage engine to use
  --dbpath arg                   directory for datafiles - defaults to
                                 \data\db\ which is C:\data\db\ based on the
                                 current working drive
  --directoryperdb               each database will be stored in a separate
                                 directory
  --noprealloc                   disable data file preallocation - will often
                                 hurt performance
  --nssize arg (=16)             .ns file size (in MB) for new databases
  --quota                        limits each database to a certain number of
                                 files (8 default)
  --quotaFiles arg               number of files allowed per db, implies
                                 --quota
  --smallfiles                   use a smaller default file size
  --syncdelay arg (=60)          seconds between disk syncs (0=never, but not
                                 recommended)
  --upgrade                      upgrade db if needed
  --repair                       run repair on all dbs
  --repairpath arg               root directory for repair files - defaults to
                                 dbpath
  --journal                      enable journaling
  --nojournal                    disable journaling (journaling is on by
                                 default for 64 bit)
  --journalOptions arg           journal diagnostic options
  --journalCommitInterval arg    how often to group/batch commit (ms)
```

I am using win-32 bit system .Please help em to run MongoDB in specific folder.

Comment: path environment variable should contain path till bin dir i.e. c:\\mongodb\bin and not c:\\mongodb

Comment: paste your exact command to start mongodb

Comment: @ Nachiket : i set the path as per you and typed the exact command "mongod --dbpath pathname " but again it is throwing the second message which is explaining above.

Comment: you need to add full path to "path" variable and then start a new session and then try. It won't work in same session.